# How to concatenate ranges using formulas, even when there are blanks to be considered on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, range, google-sheets-formula, transpose

The problem consists of concatenating multiple horizontal ranges containing product1, brand1, price1, product2, brand2, price2 and so on, even when the cells are blank.

Here's a link to a working example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1poZW2JAEu419BnOzXVe7-Sq777moXvH_o16NKZtkjAE/edit?usp=sharing

I have tried:
`=transpose(sheet1A2:C),transpose(sheet1D:F)`
`{sheet1A2:C,sheet1D:F}`
I have also tried filtering it, but none has worked so far.

Any help will be appreciated.

Cheers,
Antonio

Comment: It seems like it is very tricky to just solely use multiple pre-loaded functions with `TRANSPOSE` for your sheet data. Would you like to try a custom sheet function via an [Apps Script code](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#creating_a_bound_script) implementation that will give the same exact result instead?

Comment: How accurately does your sample spreadsheet setup reflect your actual sheet? For instance, will each line have a max of three products with their brands and pricing? Or are there actually more? Are the column headers actually "Product 1," "Product 2," etc.? Or are those other text? It is usually best to share a link to a copy of your ACTUAL sheet with a few lines of realistic data in place. Otherwise, it is both difficult to approach solutions and difficult to try to then modify those generic solutions to a real sheet later.

Comment: Hi @IrvinJayG. Thank you! That also works, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer according to what you have shared, with the assumption that your headers *will not* be "Product1" or "Brand1" but rather actual names of products and brands which are not similar to one another.

First, never put dissimilar charts or results below a working database that will grow over time. For this reason, I have added two new sheets to your spreadsheet. The first is a duplicate of your first sheet ("Página1 - Erik") which *only* has your database headers and data. The results formula is then in another sheet ("Erik Help"), in cell A2. This formula refers to the cleaned sheet "Página1 - Erik":

`=ArrayFormula(SPLIT(FLATTEN(FILTER('Página1 - Erik'!A3:A&"|"&FILTER('Página1 - Erik'!B3:J;MOD(COLUMN('Página1 - Erik'!B3:J3)-2;3)=0)&"|"&FILTER('Página1 - Erik'!B3:J;MOD(COLUMN('Página1'!B3:J3)-3;3)=0)&"|"&FILTER('Página1 - Erik'!B3:J;MOD(COLUMN('Página1 - Erik'!B3:J3)-4;3)=0);'Página1 - Erik'!A3:A<>""));"|";1;0))`

It is a similar approach to what player0 offered, but instead of relying on similarity of header text, it relies on column patterns.

I will leave it to you to modify the formula as necessary to apply to your actual data set when the time comes.

Comment: Hi, Erik ! This did work indeed! Thanks a million. Myfault on the data made available. The original version is separated - as it should be. Again, thanks for your time!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A3:A4&"×"&
 FILTER(A3:4; REGEXMATCH(A2:2; "Product.*"))&"×"&
 FILTER(A3:4; REGEXMATCH(A2:2; "Brand.*"))&"×"&
 FILTER(A3:4; REGEXMATCH(A2:2; "Price.*"))); "×");
 "where Col2 is not null"))
```

[image]

### update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A3:A4&"×"&
 FILTER(A3:4; REGEXMATCH(A2:2; "Product.*"))&"×"&
 FILTER(A3:4; REGEXMATCH(A2:2; "Brand.*"))&"×"&
 FILTER(A3:4; REGEXMATCH(A2:2; "Price.*"))); "×"))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thank you! However, This is eliminating the row where one of the transposed product is blank and that is actually needed.

Comment: @AntonioSantos answer updated

Answer (score 1):

### Alternative Solution:

You can also try this [bound script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#creating_a_bound_script) below and add it to your sheet for a simpler function use:

```
function transposeBy3(data) {
  var oneData = []
  var final = [];
  var start = 0;
  var end = 3;
  data.forEach(raw => {
    raw.forEach(value => {
      oneData.push(value);
    })
  })
  if(oneData.length%3 == 0){
    for(y=0; y<oneData.length; y++){
      final.push(oneData.slice(start, end));
      start = start + 3;
      end = end + 3;
    }
  }
  return final;
}
```

### Sample

> *After saving the bound script on your spreadsheet file, on cell `B11`, you can put this custom function `=transposeBy3(B3:J4)` as seen below*

[image]

Comment: If we answered your question, you may want to click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved & they'll easily see this post on their searches.

Comment: Hi! This works as well. I wish I could mark more than one answer as correct! Thanks a million for your time!